# ORA-06550: line 15, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: plsql, cursor

> I get following error:
>
> LOOP
>
> *
>
> ERROR at line 15:
>
> ORA-06550: line 15, column 1:
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol"LOOP" when expecting one of the following: . ( % ; for
>
> The symbol "; was inserted before "LOOP" to continue.
>
> ORA-06550: line 39, column 1:
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CLOSE"

```
DECLARE

CURSOR C1
IS
select B.PTN_STATUS,B.SUBSCRIBER_NO,A.PTN from DVC_REFRESH_Q_TEMP A, subscriber_rsource B where A.PTN=B.PTN;

ptn_sts DVC_REFRESH_Q_TEMP.PTN_STATUS%TYPE;
ptn DVC_REFRESH_Q_TEMP.PTN%TYPE;
subs_no DVC_REFRESH_Q_TEMP.SUBSCRIBER_NO%TYPE;

BEGIN

OPEN C1

LOOP
FETCH C1 into ptn_sts,subs_no,ptn;

EXIT when C1%notfound;

update DVC_REFRESH_Q_TEMP set PTN_STATUS=ptn_sts where PTN=ptn;

if ptn_sts='A' then

update DVC_REFRESH_Q_TEMP set SUBSCRIBER_NO=subs_no where PTN=ptn;

else

dbms_output.put_line('Subscriber number will be empty');

end if;

INSERT into dvc_refresh_q(dvc_name,subscriber_no,nms_ftr_ref,sys_update_date,operator_id,application_id,status)
select dvc_name,subscriber_no,nms_ftr_ref,sysdate,87952,'DRFSCR',null from dvc_refresh_q_temp where PTN_STATUS='A';



END LOOP;

CLOSE C1;

END;

/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just forgot the ; after `OPEN C1`.